# use of TextWatcher() in android

Tags: android, textwatcher

i am building an app where if the user enters an "o" or "O" in the start of the edit text then the following should be executed:

replace the entered "o"or "O" with "P" at runtime in the EditText and set the TextView to "ORANGE".

Similarly, if the user enters "g" or "G" then the entered "g"or "G" should be replace with "P" at runtime in EditText and set the TextView to "Green". 
and so on....
how can i accomplish this.I have use TextWatcher() but unable to achieve the goal.Help will be appreciated

```
package com.example.answer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class data extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}

Button start, startFor;
EditText sendET;
TextView gotAnswer, result;
int flag = 1;
TextWatcher tt = null;
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initialize();

    final EditText sendET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendet);

    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    tt = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            sendET.setSelection(s.length());

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (sendET.getText().toString() == "o") {
                flag = 0;
            }
            sendET.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
            if (flag == 0) {
                sendET.setText(sendET.getText().toString()
                        .replaceAll("o", "P"));
                result.setText("ORANGE");

            }
            sendET.addTextChangedListener(tt);

        }
    };
    sendET.addTextChangedListener(tt);
}

private void initialize() {
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sendET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendet);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:

        String bread = sendET.getText().toString();
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        result.setText(bread);
        /*
         * Bundle basket = new Bundle(); basket.putString("key", bread);
         * Intent a = new Intent(data.this, openedclass.class);
         * a.putExtras(basket); startActivity(a); break;
         */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to break down your question into the methods that you think are not functioning correctly? I think that this may help SO users debug your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sendET.getText().toString() == "o")
```

This is wrong. It's not how you check string equality in Java. Correct usage:

```
if(sendET.getText().toString().equals("o"))
```

Also, you remove your listener and add it again. I don't know your app logic, but I guess you don't want `addTextChangedListener`:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        if (sendET.getText().toString() == "o") {
            flag = 0;
        }
        sendET.removeTextChangedListener(tt); // REMOVING
        if (flag == 0) {
            sendET.setText(sendET.getText().toString()
                    .replaceAll("o", "P"));
            result.setText("ORANGE");

        }
        sendET.addTextChangedListener(tt); // ADDING AGAIN

    }
```